# On board sound card is not being detected by my PC

Tags: windows-10, audio, amd-radeon, sound-card, amd-ryzen

I've just finished my first build, everything was working fine until a corrupted driver forced me to reinstall windows clean. Now my onboard sound is not working at all. It is basically not being detected by the PC. It doesn't appear in the device manager nor in the troubleshooting for audio devices.

At first, I thought it was a hardware issue with the Motherboard so I ordered a new one, exchanged the old one and reinstalled Windows clean. It didn't solve the problem. I'm getting sound from my GPU through HDMI but the audio jacks are not working. If I plug somethin on them its not detected by the PC.

I have reinstalled Windows clean since around 5 times with no luck. Reinstalled the Realtek HD audio driver several times with no luck.

My hardware:
MB: Asus prime B450 plus
CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 2700x
GPU: AMD Radeon 580X
RAM: 4x8GB Corsair Ballistix

OS: Windows 10 Pro

Comment: Did you check with some Live Linux distro, does it detect onboard sound? Did you try an earlier version of Driver? After you do a clean install of Windows 10, before installing Realtek Audio driver, does Windows 10 detect onboard audio? Did you check if for some reasons, onboard sound is disabled in the Firmware (BIOS/UEFI)?

Comment: I have not tried with Linux or other OS I can give it a shot, I have installed an earlier version of the driver too. After a clean install of Windows 10 the PC still doesn't recognize the device. In the BIOS the HD Audio Device is currently enabled.

Comment: Disable and Re-enable in BIOS and see if it makes any difference. Also this may or may not help but just try it out. Shut down Windows, switch off the mains, then disconnect PSU power connectors from the board and then long press Power button on front panel for at least 30 seconds. This shall clear the board off any residual static charges. Now connect PSU and check again.

Comment: Was the Realtek audio driver you repeatedly installed directly from ASUS?  There was also a BIOS update for this mobo on February 9, 2021 which you may want to try applying.  [ASUS US downloads for Prime B450-PLUS](https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards-Components/Motherboards/All-series/PRIME-B450-PLUS/HelpDesk_Download/)

Comment: @patkim I disabled and re-enabled the setting in BIOS but no result, also did the 30 seconds pushing the power button and also no luck

Comment: @Blaelph All drivers I have installed come from the official ASUS site. I didn't have the new BIOS update in my mobo but now I did it, however there's no change. Still no onboard sound

Comment: Did you try some other OS like Live Linux or any other Windows PE based rescue discs?

Comment: I haven't been able to install another OS, however it comes to my mind, my PSU is 650 W with the rig I have, is it possible that I'm not getting enough power? I don't have other issues so far even if I play a high GPU demanding game

Comment: Sorry about no news.. I finally tried Linux.. no luck.. I think I have a second faulty mobo

Comment: Just for the sake of continuing this thread because I see there's a lot of people with the issue but no solved ones. I have changed to a ROG Strix mobo, the gamning II, at the begining it worked, perfectly fine, then I turned my PC off and the next morning it stopped working. After some tries I realized that when the PC gets a bit hot, I restart it and the sound comes back. I believe there must be some thermal paste some place that's not letting the CPU sit correctly, I'll give it a clean to see if it improves. Totally a HW issue